# How do i completely erase an array and replace it with a vector?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I've been working on this assignment for my class for about a day and I've completed just about everything. The only thing I'm missing is removing my array and replacing it with a vector.

```
#ifndef MENU
#define MENU
#include <vector>
const int MAXCOUNT = 20;
struct menuItem
{
    void(*func)();
    char decript[50];
};
class Menu
{
private:
    //vector <int> v;       i tried replacing the "mi"'s in the menu.cpp file with v.push_back but i kept getting pointer errors      
    menuItem mi[MAXCOUNT];      
    int count = 0;              
    void runSelection();
public:
    Menu();
    void addMenu(char *Description, void(*f)());
    void runMenu();
    void waitKey();
};
#endif
```

This is the cpp file. Im trying to replace the array mi with v. I know im missing something but I can't figure it out so I'm just posting it working with an array.

```
 Menu::Menu()
    :count(0)
{

}
void Menu::addMenu(char *Description, void(*f)())
{
    if (count < MAXCOUNT)
    {
        this->mi[count].func = f;
        strcpy(this->mi[count].decript, Description);
        count++;
    }
}
void Menu::runMenu()
{

    for (;;)
    {
        system("CLS");
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            cout << this->mi[i].decript << endl;

        }
        runSelection();
    }
}
void Menu::waitKey()
{
    cout << "Press any key to continue" << endl;
    while (!_kbhit());
    fflush(stdin);
}
void Menu::runSelection()
{
    int select;
    cin >> select;
    if (select <= count)
        this->mi[select - 1].func();

}
```

Comment: What did you try exactly? And what errors did you get?

Comment: i was creating a vector, vector<int> v;

Comment: then replacing mi with with v.push_back in my cpp

Comment: Please edit your question to show precisely what you did.

Comment: Why are you replacing an array of `menuItem` with a vector of `int`?

Comment: brain fart, this was my first experience with vectors and I assumed it was used like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way should be to replace

```
    menuItem mi[MAXCOUNT];
```

with

```
   std::vector<menuItem> mi;
```

and initialize it in your constructor properly

```
Menu::Menu()
    :count(0)
    ,mi(MAXCOUNT)
{

}
```

Supposed you had working code before, this should replace the raw array seamlessly.

---

With the current c++ standard you can even simply use

```
   std::array<menuItem,MAXCOUNT> mi;
```

this wouldn't even require initialization in the constructor.

Comment: it worked perfectly. Wow you can use the struct as a type in the vector?

Comment: and in the my functions I dont have to use .push_back at all?

Comment: this 100% kills the array in my project? That's awesome.

Comment: @dnun99 I'll give you even another option.

Comment: did u type array on purpose? if so you can include the size in this way?

Comment: @dnun99 Yes, of course. It's different from `std::vector`, see [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) please.

Comment: are these new? my professor is kinda old school and ive never seen something like this. do u recommend any books with modern programming?

Comment: @dnun99 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @dnun99 Most professors are quite old school, I'm old school as well but the difference may be I'm using the language in industry and not at university.

Comment: Yea I suppose fundamentals are more important in academics. Thank you for all your help.